# Facebook Graph API Feeds Summary Count

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Some of the aspects of the Facebook Graph API allow you to use summary and/or limit parameters to prevent the pagination of results. The "total_count" can then be easily read.

I want the **total count of a user's posts**, but the posts endpoint seems to ignore the summary parameter and instead seems to produce paginated results no matter what. Thus if I want the count, I need to scroll through each page, literally incrementing a counter as I go. This is unsustainable for larger amounts of posts (max 25 per page).

How can I get the total Posts count with a single API call?

The endpoint is described in the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed (note that "posts" is a variant of "feed").